# place() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, arguments

I srtuggle with the TypeError: " place_configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given". I don't understand why tkinter has a problem with the number of arguments I give to the place method. Normally I did place(x=45, y=240) and changed the y value all the time in a hard coding style. Now I want to make it easier using variables, for the case that maybe someone wants to change the values one time. When I do this, the Error appears. Thanks for your help already.

````
        x = 45;
        y = 240;
        self.counter = 0

        

        # Creation of checkbuttons
        self.values_checkboxes_bitness={"32 and 64 Bit": 0, "32 Bit": 1, "64 Bit": 2}
        self.values_checkboxes_debugRelease={"rebug and release": 0, "debug": 1, "release": 2}

        for text in self.values_checkboxes_bitness:
            self.counter+=1
            bitnessCB = Checkbutton( text=text,variable=self.int_var_one, onvalue=self.values_checkboxes_bitness[text], offvalue=3,
                               command=partial(self.checkbox_clicked, self.int_var_one, self.int_var_one_comp,
                                               self.int_var_one_no_checkout,
                                              self.int_var_one_buildtype))
            bitnessCB.pack()
            bitnessCB.config(font=("Helvetica", 10))

        for text in self.values_checkboxes_debugRelease:
            self.counter+=1

        relDebCB =  Checkbutton(text=text,variable=self.int_var_one_comp, onvalue=self.values_checkboxes_debugRelease[text], offvalue=3,
                           command=partial(self.checkbox_clicked, self.int_var_one, self.int_var_one_comp,
                                           self.int_var_one_no_checkout,
                                          self.int_var_one_buildtype))

        relDebCB.config(font=("Helvetica", 10))
        if self.counter > 0:
            y += 30
            relDebCB.place(x,y)
        else:
            relDebCB.place(x,y)```

TypeError: place_configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
````

Comment: I think you need to provide keyword arguments as `relDebCB.place(x=x,y=y)`

Answer (score 1):

The `x` and `y` parameters must be specified as key-value pairs.

Change `relDebCB.place(x,y)` to `relDebCB.place(x=x,y=y)`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the call `relDebCB.place(x,y)` you pass three arguments to the method `.place()`. The first argument is the object stored in `relDebCB`. The other two are positional arguments.

So, if your definition of the method only has two arguments, you pass one too many.

Since you did not provide the code, I guess that the function definition looks something like:

```
def place(x,y):
   pass ## Here goes your code
```

Instead, it should look like:

```
def place(self,x,y):
   pass ## Here goes your code
```

The first argument in any method of a class should be `self`, as the first argument passed to any method is the object itself.

EDIT: Unless, of course, you don't have a method `.place()` but want to use the place manager of tkinter, as Space commented. Then, you would just have to call it with named arguments instead of positional arguments:

```
relDebCB.place(x=x,y=y)
```

Comment: Since the Exception `TypeError: place_configure() ...` is raised, my guess is OP is trying to call the `place` Tk geometry manager, not define a method with the same name.

Comment: Thanks! Did not think of that and amended the answer. I never use this method, myself, as I am a strict .grid()-user.

Answer (score 0):

The weird thing about the `place` method is that the first argument specifies if you want to move it to another master/root window, which is uncommon. So, you must specify that you want the x position and y position, like this, with key-value pairs:

```py
widget.place(x = x, y = y)
```

You can also use `relx` and `rely`, which specify what percentage of the page to move it to. For example, moving it to the center, and making it stay there, without regard for screen size, would require this code:

```py
widget = Frame(..., anchor = CENTER)
widget.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5)
```

You must specify the anchor as `CENTER`, or you can use `"center"`, as they are the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot it! It has been very helpfull.

Comment: `Frame` does not have `anchor` option, do you mean `place(..., anchor=CENTER)`?